# Vertica 6.1: vsql creashes with large resultset

Tags: client, vertica

I'm writing a script to export data from our Vertica cluster.
The command I'm using is:

```
vsql MY_DB_NAME -At -F$'\t' -o /data/vertica_archive/MY_DATA_2015_07_01.tsv  -c "select * from DATA_TABLE where ts_date ='2015-07-01';"
```

Sporadically resulting with:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
connection to server was lost
```

All of our queries are simple "select * from TABLE where ts_date=DATE", but some of the queries result-set will generate a 10GB files.

Example row count:

```
MY_DB=> select count(*) from DATA_TABLE where ts_date ='2015-07-01';
  count
----------
 18213295
(1 row)
```

Is there any exit code documentation or can any one suggest how to debug?

Comment: It would be helpful to know your environment (nodes, specs, network, etc.)

Comment: Update:
opening vsql and leaving it open for some time also drops the connection:
`MY_DB=> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM NODES;
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
MY_DB=>`

Comment: You're still not giving any information on the environment. Is there a connection timeout on the pool?

Comment: How can I check for timeout? 
My cluster is composed of 4 nodes, 16-cores, 124GB memory, 4.3TB spin disks.
Vertica 6.1, Centos 5.9

Comment: Look at `queuetimeout` in `resource_pools`.

Comment: The general resource pool has queuetimeout of 300

Comment: The queuetimeout for the general resource pool is 300,
How can I determine the resource pool used for the queries I run?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your environment, there are a couple things you can try. The first being adding an additional filter to make the output file smaller. The other is using a [pipe viewer](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/CopyingDataUsingVsql.htm) to monitor the progress.

If you're using the enterprise edition, you should report the issue to support.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RUNTIMECAP or QUEUETIMEOUT of the resource pool used for this query. 
 I do hope you are doing this locally on the server and then copy them out of your server.
 Try to zip before moving it. 
**See example:**

```
vsql -U dbadmin -w dbadmin -F $'|' -At -c "SELECT * FROM table" | gzip -c > '/vertica/backup_table_one.gz'
```

You will save bandwidth and time as well.

Comment: Indeed I execute locally on the server